# Setup Linux Multicasting Router for RHEL 6

Tags: routing, router, linux, multicast, route-server

This is my first visit into the world of network multicasting on Linux.

I understand how to change the ethernet port configuration and system routing tables to add multicasting.

I want setup a designated RHEL 6 Linux system as a router for multicast packets.

I've googled a lot of documentation but other than setting up the ethernet port and routing table (and setting standard IP forwarding)...I don't see anything else to do.  I have handled the IPtables configuration as well.  IP_MULTICAST is set in the kernel.

Do I need a special routing daemon package and are there any other configuration items that I need to address to make this happen?

Comment: You will probably find better support for networking for Linux on [sf] or one of the Linux SE sites.

Answer (score 1):

There is no "ethernet port configuration" necessary, and the "system routing tables" have nothing at all to do with multicast.

Multicast routing requires multicast routing software (pimd, mrouted, etc.) and a kernel with mroute capabilities. It is a completely different mechanism from IPv4 and IPv6 unicast routing.

I do multicast routing with a linux system. I would not recommend it. Ever. Multicast routing support on linux is abysmal. The software packages for do it are few, nearly abandoned, have worthless documentation, and barely work. Then there's the linux kernel limitations -- the use of a 32bit bitmask limits the number of interfaces to about 28.

Comment: I appreciate your comments.  In the standard RHEL 6, Centos 6, Centos 7, I have been unable to find the necessary multicasting routing software.  And that is what has been requested to have happen.  What do I do?

Comment: Now you see the complexity of the task. Very few distros ship any multicast routing packages, because they all suck and no one wants to maintain the package.

Answer (score 1):

@mdpc - There are a lot of discussions/trouble-shooting assistance from within the Linux communities.

See for example this forum http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1405360  and your question has been asked before:-
http://markmail.org/message/njv7d2huanz5ibdc#query:+page:1+mid:y3dshxr5hkt3m5y5+state:results

You really want to ask this question at https://unix.stackexchange.com/

And read this too: http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Multicast-HOWTO-3.html

Quite unsure if RedHat servers has a running kernel with your required options enabled. After checking on your .config file, you "may" have to recompile a test kernel for your needs before going production.

My $00.02, I'd go bsd for critical/production servers: http://bsdrp.net/documentation/examples/multicast_with_pim-sm